# How to decrease 1 number every day from 365

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem how to decrease 1 number every  from 365.
  suppose today is my number 365 it will be update tomorrow in 364  then next day 363 next 362 till number should  be 0.

```
$a=365;
mysql_query("update record set number='".$a."'");

?>
```

I am not able to write code for this problem please help me.
      Thanks for your great help

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions - they are deprecated.

Comment: What do you want to happen in a leap year?

Answer (score 2):

If you're running this query once a day via a cron job etc:

```
mysql_query("update record set number = (number - 1) WHERE number >= 0");
```

Answer (score 1):

The countdown query should be

```
update record 
set number = number - 1
where id = :id: -- use where clause if you need to identify particular record
```

But, updating the count each day is a little clumsy. If you need number of days until some date, then it is much better to only **store only the target date** and then **report the number of remaining days in the select**:

```
select datediff(future_date, NOW())
```

This way you don't have to make the daily updates. No need for cron job.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative take from the cron based answers.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2013-12-3');//Start date of the countdown
$diff = $now->diff($start);

$a= max(365 - $diff->days,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update record set number = number - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$a=365;  
$number = $a - 1;
mysql_query("update record set number='".$number."'");
```